Documentary about the mystery man
This is a true story documentary. I have watched one of the documentary  on the YouTube. 
Story line:
The story goes like this one person appears in Alaska or Canada near the mountain area. He built his own shelter from woods, after some time the police start getting suspicious that who this mystery man is. When police came to check, there is a shooting from that person, at that time police pull themselves as they do not had time and man-power but later they came with much man-power and that battle lasted for several hours.  In last the mystery man run-away from cops to north side. Police keep on chasing him and he keep on going in ice area further north. 
At one point he reaches to the one of the big mountain and police think that the can not cross the mountain, but he did cross. That was the interesting part of the documentary as it was very hard to cross without enough equipment. After further police chase they found him and in shooting police killed him with one shot in back. And later buried him. BUT HIS IDENTITY NEVER REVEALED.
After so many years. Archeologists/forensic expert start working on this story and in this documentary they found his grave and dug up that, found the remains and start doing forensic investigation. One interesting thing they found from his teeth is that, he has done some treatment to the teeth and it was costly during those days(during those days means that man's story might be around 1950 or 1900), hence this story from that time as far as I remembered from that show. And other thing, during this forensic investigation they found that bullet from his body remains which killed him.
But after all forensic investigations also they could not find the identity of this man. This documentary probably made by the national geography or discovery or similar channels which are front in making documentaries. 
I forgot the title of documentary and could not find on YouTube. I watched this on YouTube around 1 year ago. Please can anybody guess which documentary is this?

May be, but this documentary was very special, it was about to identify that mystery man. That was whole theme of this documentary, it was not any regular forensic investigation.  And I have posted 2-3 unique incidences from that documentary. May be this information helps somebody.

Sorry if it is not clear, it was just one documentary of about 60 -90 minutes. And for climax I mean, it was the remembering part of the documentary. I wil edit. Thanks.

@MeatTrademark, Hi, just updated both, actually it was not my intention to not do that, Just I am living in different Time-Zone, so yesterday I had to leave at that point as it was 3:00am at my side, already too late, but again today I got time to do that...:) Thanks

The Documentary with same theme as specified in the question can be found on YouTube with the following link. "Arctic Manhunt"

Youtube Source: The excerpt which has been provided on the YouTube at above mentioned link I am posting as it is(Note: Non-edited, credit goes to creator of that excerpt at above mentioned link) and apart from the question, it included more details about this documentary.


Arctic Manhunt is a dramatic forensic documentary that attempts to identify the mystery man at the center of one of the biggest manhunts in Canadian history. Equal parts criminological exam footage and creative re-enactments, this episode of Pure History Specials offers a stylized, moody investigation into one of Canada's greatest unsolved mysteries.
On Christmas Day, 1931, the Royal Canadian Mounted Police, with the assistance of aboriginal trackers, approached a rural cabin near the Arctic Circle. They were there to question an unknown trapper about vandalized trap lines but were met with open fire instead of answers. Over the next 49 days one of the largest criminal searches in Canadian history ensued, taking the RCMP above the Arctic Circle where they had to endure harsh weather conditions on top of firefights with the mysterious fugitive they were pursuing. Ending with the trapper's suicide, police found $2,400 in cash on his body but nothing to identify him or indicate why he was on the run.
Some speculate he was a Chicago gangster connected to Al Capone while others suspect he may have been a murderer responsible for a string of unsolved homicides across the Great White North. Others have posited that he was just a down-on-his-luck farmer from North Dakota. Despite photographs and fingerprints, police agencies across North America failed to identify the mystery man time and again. Almost 80 years later, forensic experts dig up the remains of the fugitive to try and determine his identity once and for all.
Through skeletal remains and facial reconstruction technology, forensic scientists piece together a narrative of the RCMP's pursuit of the mystery man through the Canadian wilds, but their only hope of finding a positive identification rests in obtaining a reliable sample of DNA from the fugitive's remains. Criminal profilers offer additional insight in an effort to fill in the details of who this fugitive was, and what he was running from.
Arctic Manhunt weaves through time, taking viewers to the past where they imagine the events of the manhunt, and into the forensic labs of today where scientists work to close the book on this decades-old cold case.


Wikipedia source: You can find the further detail explanation of this story on wikipedia link also title as Albert Johnson (criminal) 


You might want to elaborate in which way this fits the details from the question in order to flesh out this answer a little more.

But how can I elaborate, if I elaborate, it is the same thing what I wrote in question. The video is itself elaboration. Hence if person see the video, he will find it. If you want me to write in some other way please let me know, might be I am not aware here about that. Thanks

You could describe the major parts in the documentatry that match the details in the question. It's about convincing future readers of this answer that it is the correct one. Link-only answer or answer without any explanations are highly discouraged. This hold equally for self-answers and/or identification question as it holds for all other kinds of questions and answers.

Ohhh..that way..I got you, I will update the answer. Very Thanks
